# How to fetch records with lastest 2 version numbers

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

How to fetch records with latest 2 version numbers from a table using SQL query.
I want to fetch `user ids` for a tracking `id` for the last 2 versions.

Below is my table description:

```
TRACKING_ID ,
User_id,
Version_number
```

Below query gives me the user id having the latest version.

```
Select user_id 
from table t1 
join 
(select tracking_id,max(version_number) as version_number 
from table 
 group by tracking_id ) t2
    on t1.tracking_id=t2.tracking_id
    and t1.version_number=t2.version_number
```

Appreciate your response.

Comment: how do you define latest version numbers?

Comment: It would help to see sample data/expected results.  I think a simply analytic such as row_number over (partition by ... order by ...) would work.

Comment: @xQbert : yes it did work

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT  tracking_id,
        user_id,
        version_number
FROM (  SELECT  *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY tracking_id ORDER BY version_number DESC) AS RN
        FROM YourTable) AS T
WHERE RN <= 2
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully understand the question but something like this may point you in the correct direction.

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT tracking_ID, user_ID, version_number,
Row_number() over (partition by USER_ID, Version_number desc) as RN)
SELECT * 
FROM cte 
WHERE RN <= 2;
```

I'm not sure if the user_ID or the tracking_ID needs to be partitioned...